# searching for file in alternating path

Tags: excel, vba, automation

I have a VBA code that finds and lists all files and folders from a specified folder. Here it is:

```
Sub Example1()
Dim objFSO As Object
Dim objFolder As Object
Dim objFile As Object
Dim i As Integer
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder("C:\Desktop\Test\2015\11-16")
i = 1
For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
   Cells(i + 1, 1) = objFile.Name
    Cells(i + 1, 2) = objFile.Path
    i = i + 1
Next objFile
End Sub
```

*
1)How to get current month? 2)How to get current year?  3)How to combine current month/year in this format M-YY and insert it into the folder path?

Answer (score 0):

Put the for loop for files into another loop for months.

```
Imports System
Module module1
    Sub Main()
    Dim objFSO As Object
    Dim objFolder As Object
    Dim objFile As Object
    Dim i As Integer
    objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    For month As Integer = 11 to 12
        Dim folderPath As String = "C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Test\2015\" & month & "-16"
        Console.WriteLine("Folder path = " & folderPath)
        objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(folderPath)
        i = 1
        For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
            ' Cells(i + 1, 1) = objFile.Name
            Console.WriteLine("Cells(" & (i + 1) & ", 1) = " & objFile.Name)
            ' Cells(i + 1, 2) = objFile.Path
            Console.WriteLine("Cells(" & (i + 1) & ", 2) = " & objFile.Path)
            i = i + 1
        Next objFile
    Next month

    End Sub
End Module
```

If you need to loop on year as well, you could put the two loops above inside another loop for years. The following code works from 2016 to 2099.

```
Sub Example1()
Dim objFSO As Object
Dim objFolder As Object
Dim objFile As Object
Dim i As Integer
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

For year As Integer = 16 to 99
    For month As Integer = 11 to 12
        Dim folderPath As String = "C:\Desktop\Test\2015\" & month & "-" & year
        Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(folderPath)
        i = 1
        For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
            Cells(i + 1, 1) = objFile.Name
            Cells(i + 1, 2) = objFile.Path
            i = i + 1
        Next objFile
    Next month
Next year

End Sub
```

Comment: So in  this line: folderPath = "C:\Desktop\Test\2015\" & month & "-16"......& month &....means it selects the current month?

Comment: I've added for years as well, assuming different years folders are inside the 2015 folder (you can change that too)..

Comment: What if I want it to search each time the prior month to the current date?

Comment: Then instead of increasing the month in the loop, you will need to decrease it. Just replace `For month = 11 to 12` with `For month = 11 to 1 Step -1`. That way it will go from 11, 10, 9, 8.. to 1.

Comment: It gives me an error for the "For Month = 11 to 12" line, Compile error: Argument not optional

Comment: Sorry it should be `For month As Integer = 11 to 12`. I've updated it in the code above. I've not tested it, so bear with me :)

Comment: no worries, thanks for all the help but it still gives an error, different error this time.

Comment: What's the erorr?

Comment: Try it now. Didn't declare a string type for variable folderPath.

Comment: The same error for the line For month As Integer = 11 to 12

Comment: I've updated the code above. The error was due to using `Set` statements, which are no longer supported. Further, I've commented out the `Cell(i + 1, 1) = ...` lines and instead written an output to the console. I've compiled and tested the code and it is working fine. (I've updated on the first code block above.. you can get the idea for the second one from the first one)